# Handlebar template not rendering in cordova

Tags: cordova, zepto, handlebarshelper

I am new to Handlebar js and using it for cordova app development. I just tried with static html content. After compile, HTML content is not rendering.

**cordova 6.0, 
Android 4.4, 
Javascript library am using "Zepto"**

This is my code:

```
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
   <div class="entry">
       <h1>Testing</h1>
       <div class="body">
           Test
       </div>
   </div>
</script>

var source = $("#entry-template").html();
template = Handlebars.compile(source);
$("#mainbox").append(template);
```

**The output am getting is:**

```
FUNCTION E(A,B){RETURN F||(F=D()),F.CALL(THIS,A,B))
```

Answer (score 2):

Template is a function so you can't append it.

You must pass your data to template and append return value for example:

**Html**

```
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div class="entry">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <div class="body">
      {{body}}
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

**javascript**

```
var source   = $("#entry-template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var context = {title: "My New Post", body: "This is my first post!"};
var html    = template(context);
```

You must append the html var that contains return value from template() function

```
$("#mainbox").append(html);
```